# How could the message be exchanged? _networking_

Tags: java

I have made my pc both server and client and am able to pass messages from one cmd window to another.
But i am still able to do so when i am not connected to internet.**How is that possible.?***This is My code.*

```
import java.net.*;
 class tester {
  static int pos=0; 
  static byte buffer[]=new byte[100];

   static void Client() throws Exception {
   InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
  DatagramSocket ds=new DatagramSocket();
   while(pos<buffer.length) {
    int c=System.in.read();
    buffer[pos++]=(byte)c;
    if((char)c=='\n')
      break;
   }
  ds.send(new DatagramPacket(buffer,pos,address,3000));

}          
 static void Server() throws Exception {
 InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
 DatagramSocket ds=new DatagramSocket(3000,address);
 DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
 ds.receive(dp);
 String s=new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());
 System.out.print(s);
}
 public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {
  if(args.length==1) {
 Client();  }
    else {
     Server();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you not understand the answer to your first question?

Your computer has networking enabled. Your server is listening on 127.0.0.1 and your client is sending to 127.0.0.1.

`InetAddress.getLocalHost()` returns the loopback address if you have not been assigned a routeable IP address.